# SMTP client stopped working after updating to netcore 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, openssl, ssl-certificate, smtpclient, asp.net-core-3.1

After updating my asp.net-core web API project from 2.2 to 3.1 I'm getting following exception, when trying to send an e-mail via the `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`:

```
- 2020-02-09 14:40:26.8163  15  ( SmtpClient.OnSendCompleted => <>c__DisplayClass78_0.<SendMailAsync>b__0 => SmtpClient.HandleCompletion )  -  Error Failed to send E-Mail. -- ( Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.TlsStreamAuthenticateCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception source)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.EndGetConnection(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The API's endpoints are configured via the Kestrel-section in appsettings.json

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://myapidomain:80"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://www.myapidomain:443",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": <path to pfx file>,
          "Password": <password>
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

This is how I use the `SmtpClient`:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient(_options.MailServiceHost, _options.MailServicePort))
{
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.ClientCertificates.Add(_certificate);
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_options.MailAccountName, _options.MailAccountPassword);

    var mail = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress(author),
        Body = body,
        Subject = subject,
        Sender = new MailAddress(author),
        SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        HeadersEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
    };

    mail.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "content=text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
    mail.To.Add(receiver);
    mail.ReplyToList.Add(author);

    _logger.LogInformation($"Sending mail to: {receiver}");
    await client.SendMailAsync(mail);
    return true;
}
```

The above code works when I switch back to the `aspnetcore2.2` version, so I doubt this is an issue with the certificate itself (I'm using exactly the same .pfx file for both). Another important hint might be that it actually works on `aspnetcore3.1` when debugging locally with a self-signed development certificate on a Windows machine. In production, where above code fails, I'm running the API on Ubuntu.

My guess is that either something has changed with how certificates are handled in asp.net-core 3.x. or that the Windows libraries behave differently. If needed, I can also post both Startup.cs files.

Any suggestions get more details on the actual cause or how to fix this?

**Update**

As suggested by Adam, I've switched to MailKit's implementation of `SmtpClient`. The error still persists in production, but I managed to get a bit more details on the error using the `client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. I get following log prints, when inspecting the callback's `ChainStatus` property:

```
X509ChainStatusFlags: RevocationStatusUnknown
StatusInformation: unable to get certificate CRL
```

Could someone explain why the disability to get a certificate CRL causes my connection to fail? How do I fix this?

**Update 2**

Also, when I set `client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false` I get following error:

```
X509ChainStatusFlags: PartialChain
StatusInformation: unable to get local issuer certificate
Subject: CN=smtp.gmail.com, O=Google LLC, L=Mountain View, S=California, C=US 
Issuer: CN=GTS CA 1O1, O=Google Trust Services, C=US
```

**Update 3**

It appears that the netcore framework can't find the required ca certificates, because I get exactly the same error message as in Update 2, when I run following command on the Ubuntu machine:

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
--> Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

However, when I explicitly specify the ca-certificate storage path validation passes.

```
openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
--> Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

So I guess the final question is: **How do I get my aspnet-core web API to locate Ubuntu's ca-certificate storage?**

**Update 4**

I've reported this issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31514#issuecomment-583967138), maybe this issue will be addressed eventually by the dotnet team. As a (hopefully) temporary workaround I ended up validating the certificate's thumprint manually.

Comment: These SSL issues are a pain, I feel for you.  If I had to guess the difference between .net core 3 and whatever you upgraded from, the default TLS version may be different.  Can you connect to the SMTP service with a regular old client?

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions of [D.Snap's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522431/how-to-send-an-email-using-command-line) and it worked. In fact, I'm also trying to use Google's SMTP service in production.

Comment: Ok, there is one difference: The client in the example uses port 587 (`auth on, tls on`) to send the message, but MailKit's client (`useSsl: true`, `client.SslProtocols` using different combinations of flags) is not able to do so, because it gets a System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format. The ubuntu client in turn fails using port 465.

Comment: they just need to do away with email =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out why this stopped working on Linux. The netcore3.1 framework does not read from the OS's ca-certificates folder, but from

`~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/ca`

Therefore the app did not trust ANY certificates. So I downloaded Google's sample PEM file from [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/root-ca-faq#why-should-i-not-install-any-intermediate-ca-certificates), converted it into a P7B file to make sure the entire certificate chain remains intact

`openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile google-roots.pem -out google-roots.p7b`

and added the entire chain to the framework's certificate store during app startup

```
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

    options.CertificateChainFiles.ToList().ForEach(file =>
    {
        var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        collection.Import(file);
        store.AddRange(collection);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So, if you look at the documentation for [SmtpClient()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8) you can see that it is now marked as obsolete.  I'm actually quite surprised it you didn't get a compiler error, you should have but that is probably a tomorrow problem.

Microsoft recommends using the MailKit library. Links: [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/) - [GitHub](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)

I would encourage you to re-implement your code using the Mailkit library instead of using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()`.  Aside from not being obsolete, MailKit is a wonderfully easy library to use, the developers and contributers put a lot of time and thought into it.

It's reason for making the library obsolete and recommending MailKit is

> SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed

Fun fact: .Net Core 1.0 did not have access to the `System.Net.Mail` namespace and support was added in after, however by the time `System.Net.Mail` was available in .NET Core, `MailKit` was the preferred library of early .NET Core adopters.

Comment: Unfortunately switching to MailKit did not solve the issue. However I managed to get some additional information on the error (see my updated question).

Comment: I understand that this answer is not the entire solution, hopefully it was somewhat helpful.